# Rearrange bootstrap markup depending on resolution

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

At the moment I have some what similar bootstrap markup as this:

```
<div class="row clerfix">
   <div class="span4>Search</div>
   <div class="span4>Logo</div>
   <div class="span4>Navigation</div>
</div>
```

It's fine for every resolution except mobile, because I need something like this for mobile layout (Change of order):

```
<div class="row clerfix">
   <div class="span4>Logo</div>
   <div class="span4>Navigation</div>
   <div class="span4>Search</div>
</div>
```

Because span4 divs appear below each other in order, I somehow need to change that order for mobile design, is that achievable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include both in your html.

```
<div class="row clerfix hidden-phone">
    <div class="span4>Search</div>
    <div class="span4>Logo</div>
    <div class="span4>Navigation</div>
</div>

<div class="row clerfix visible-phone">
   <div class="span4>Logo</div>
   <div class="span4>Navigation</div>
   <div class="span4>Search</div>
</div>
```

<strike>Then show and hide with either [css media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) or javascript.</strike>

Thanks to the edit from @Johan `visible-phone` and `hidden-phone` are classes already [available in bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html).

Comment: Thanks for the edit Johan, maybe next time add a comment with an explanation.